# Algum programa que converta html, css e js em executável?

Tags: html5, .exe

assim como o cordova faz build de html, css e js pra apk, existe alguma solução para buildar em executável? Se sim qual programa? Obrigado!

Comment: [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)?

Comment: Sabe me dizer se ele é gratuito?

Comment: Você pode fazer uma aplicação web normal e instalar ela no pc pelo navegador, ele cria um atalho na área de trabalho. Pesquise sobre PWA

Comment: beleza amigo, vou pesquisar! abs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Electron](https://electronjs.org/), um framework de [código aberto](https://github.com/electron/electron) desenvolvido pelo GitHub.

Com o Electron, você usa JavaScript, HTML e CSS para criar aplicações desktop multiplataforma (MacOS, Linux e Windows).

Alguns exemplos de aplicações criadas com o Electron são o [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Atom](https://atom.io/) e [muito mais](https://electronjs.org/apps).

Comment: Valeu meu irmão, forte abraço!